# Persisting Playa relationship in Matrix row

Tags: matrix, playa, better-workflow

I have a matrix field that has a single-select Playa field in one of its two columns. (The other column is just text).

In one particular situation, the value of the Playa field was changed, but the old relationship still remained in the exp_playa_relationships table along with the new one. Because of this, the exp:playa:parents tag returned both the old and the new associated entry. Note that this change was made simply by selecting a new value in the Playa dropdown and saving; **not** removing the row, saving, creating a new row with the new relationship and saving again.

Here's my EE setup:

- EE 2.5.3
- Playa 4.3.3
- Matrix 2.5.3
- Better Workflow 1.5.1
- PHP 5.3.10

I understand from [this support post](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/playa_relationship_from_matrix_column_persisting_after_row_where_relations_was_created_is_removed) that something similar has been an issue in the past, but it should be fixed in the version that I have. At the moment, my only suspicion is that since I have Better Workflow installed, this could be messing with the functionality somehow.

Any suggestions or experiences with this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are still running into the problem, you need update to the latest version of each add-on and EE. That'll get you fixed up.